# TIBCO BW: can we build an ear using command line based on a .archive?

Tags: deployment, build, continuous-integration, ear, tibco

I am using TIBCO Designer 5.11 and I can build the ear using the designer based on the .archive file in my project. However, for automated builds and deployment, I would like to do the same through command line. I have multiple .archive files in my project and would like to build only a specific ear at a particular time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are the utilities "BuildEar" (to build ears) and "AppManage" to deploy/undeploy in your tra/*tra-version*/bin folder of your TIBCO installation. They are executable on commandline & could be scripted in an automated build/deployment script.

Building one specific archive within a project would look like this:

```
buildear.exe -o c:\temp\abc124.ear -ear /abc124.archive -p c:\temp\SampleService
```

(Check the help by simply executing the commands on commandline).
Hope that helps

Cheers
      Seb

Comment: P.s: there's also a commercial utility for automating building/deploying in case you might consider: https://tibant.com/

Comment: but how do I point it to a specific .archive in my project? I did not find any options for that

Comment: The option you are looking for "-ear /abc123.archive". This option specifies the relative path to the archive file.

Comment: @Seb can you incorporate this in your answer so people understand it?